# CF7, Repeatable fields and Google Sheet integration

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets, contact-form-7

I'm working with [CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) and [Repeatable Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-repeatable-fields/), I want the form submit to be sent to a Google Sheet, and I'm using [CF7 Google Sheets Connector](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/integration-for-contact-form-7-and-google-sheets/).

Now I simply want the new repeated field to be imported on the sheet. I don't even care if it's a JSON, but the field is not printed in the document.

- Tried both the field and the loop from the docs
- Repeatable fields seem to have a function for mail, but the shortcodes are not managed for all use cases

Comment: This is a really good question for the plugin developer. Have you tried asking in the support forum for the plugin, or asking the developer directly?

Comment: [Yes I did](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cf7-repeatable-fields-and-google-sheet/), it seems the plugin developer is not as active, I was hoping to have some help here.

Comment: I wouldn't ask on the support forums. Log into your account on the developers site and submit a support ticket. You'll probably get more help there. I understand wanting to get help here, but there's no code and you're asking about integration between two third-party services. It's a bit beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: They replied that the plugin won't be compatible. Shouldn't I ask here for code support at the very least? You're saying that I can't get to a specialists' forum to ask specific code questions because the plugin creators should answer it? What if they don't? Also, the code is not rocket science, I was just wondering if someone would have insights on this as it seems like a regular use case.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't ask for code support, but you didn't provide any code you've tried (saying you used the loops from the docs isn't enough), where it's failing, or any sort of errors you are getting. The scope of what you're asking is too broad. You would need to narrow it down. Also, the developer even said it wasn't compatible - which leads me to believe it's not a regular use case. I'm not saying it's not a valid question, it's just not focused enough for SO.